# how to handle scope in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working with angular js for my dashboard. I have an over all minimize button to minimize all widget and then each widget have own minimize button. I done with following script its not working.
when i click widget minimize button its minimize all widget. but i want minimize that widget only.

```
var dashboard = angular.module("dashboard",['ui.bootstrap']);
dashboard.controller('dash-control', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.isHidden = false;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
    };
    $scope.toggleonce= function()
    {   
       if( this.isHidden === true)
           this.isHidden = false;
       else
           this.isHidden = true;
    };
}]);
```

HTML code like follow:

```
<div class="contentpanel" ng-app="dashboard" ng-controller="dash-control as ctrl">
 <button class="btn btn-white" type="button" ng-click="toggle()"><i  class="fa fa-minus-square">       </i>   </button>

 <div>
<a href="" class="tooltips" ng-click="toggleonce()" title="Minimize Panel"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-show="isHidden">Contenr Heading 1</div>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-hide="isHidden">Content Description 1</div>

 </div>
<div>
<a href="" class="tooltips" ng-click="toggleonce()" title="Minimize Panel"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-show="isHidden">Contenr Heading 2</div>
<div class="row tinychart" ng-hide="isHidden">Content Description 1</div>

 </div>
......
.....
.....
</div>
```

Comment: when i click inside minimize toggleonce its minimize all widgets.

Comment: The only way to achieve what you are wanting would be to create a directive for this functionality, or use a different variable for each link tag.  This has nothing to do with `$scope`, it has everything to do with the fact that you have less variables than you have items you want to track.

Comment: If i Have more widget then what i do with that.

Comment: If by widget you mean the repeating div at the end of the html sample, it's not currently structured as a widget.  I would suggest refactoring this into a directive.

Comment: yes i meaned that only. widgets are randomly generated one. how i handle to write every directives. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather create a directive with isolated scope for represent a inner widget. for instance;

```
    dashboard.directive('myWidget',function(){

    return {
        scope:{},
        template:"<div>\r\n<a href=\"\" class=\"tooltips\" ng-click=\"toggleonce()\" title=\"Minimize Panel\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus\"><\/i><\/a>\r\n<div class=\"row tinychart\" ng-show=\"isHidden\">asdasdasd<\/div>\r\n<div class=\"row tinychart\" ng-hide=\"isHidden\">sdasdasd<\/div>\r\n\r\n <\/div>",
         link:function($scope)
         {
              $scope.isHidden = false;
              $scope.toggle = function(){
                 $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
              };

             $scope.togglesingle = function()
             {   
               if( this.isHidden === true)
                 this.isHidden = false;
               else
                 this.isHidden = true;
               };
             }

          }

});
```

Then In Html Body;

```
<div class="contentpanel" ng-app="dashboard" >
 <button class="btn btn-white" type="button" ng-click="toggle()"><i  class="fa fa-minus-square">       </i>   </button>

 <div my-widget></div>
 <div my-widget></div>
</div>
```

Note that I haven't run and check the example. I hope you got the idea.

Edited:
The ng-repeat will loop the array (list) and initiate each element to 'item' variable. You can pass that data to your directive. Check the updated code.

Comment: It wont possible for my app. Because every widget load with some content. I have to dynamically hide and show content when click minimize for particular widget/Minimize all widget at a time

Comment: You could bind the data from outer scope, so each widget will get it own data. Then inside the widget you could use that data as you want. I have edited the answer to reflect that